# Possible duplicate question on a different StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion

Today we had the question [Should IPv4 ICMP from untrusted interfaces be blocked?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/should-ipv4-icmp-from-untrusted-interfaces-be-blocked)

While looking for references to provide a good answer I found a very similar question already asked and answered in the IT Security Stack Exchange: [Is it a bad idea for a firewall to block ICMP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/is-it-a-bad-idea-for-a-firewall-to-block-icmp)

What is the right way to proceed in this case? Shall we mark the new question as a duplicate? Is it even possible to do so when the new and the old question are in two different StackExchange sites? Maybe migrate the question? Or provide an answer with a reference to the old question?

Comment: The problem is the blurry line between where a question belongs - some questions could belong on either SF or NE - some questions could belong on either SO, SF, or NE.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the right way to proceed in this case?

Answer the question on NE

> Shall we mark the new question as a duplicate?

[Duplicates only matter within a specific site on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87749/160519).  If the question already exists on serverfault, it still is not a duplicate if we get a very similar question on NE *from a different person*.  It's worth mentioning that [SE discourages cross-posting the same question between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/160519).

> Maybe migrate the question?

If it clearly is not a fit for our site, then flag for migration... I see migrations quite often on Stack Overflow.  However, I haven't seen the mods very active about question migration here, even when the questions clearly should have been posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)... this will probably change if we exit beta.

> Or provide an answer with a reference to the old question?

That's up to the people who post answers... normally I just provide a hyperlink to another site as a comment, unless I have something more to add to the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is 'on topic' here on NE, then we should answer it here. If the answer's author uses that other stack's answer as their source of knowledge, then I think a footnote link over would be warranted.

In the specific case you've mentioned, the author of the answer probably wrote from their own knowledge, so I wouldn't expect them to mention the other stack's Q/A.